# Read and Write data in the same EXCEL - No Third Party

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working in C#.Net. I will send a EXCEL File as my input and from that file i will do a process and will get the result.

I want to print the result in the same EXCEL sheet. The below code i am using to read excel.

```
 public DataTable ReadDataExcel(string filepath)
    {
        FileStream stream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = result.Tables[0];
        return dt;
    }
```

I will use this datatable for process. How to print the OUTPUT Values in the same EXCEL Sheet. Without any third party's i need to do this..

Comment: Is this xls or xlsx? Would you consider OpenXML SDK third party? Its official MS.

Comment: xls...OpenXML SDK whether this is software..? shall able to get any sample code..and more over i am using Windows Application..

Comment: OpenXML SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

Comment: but openxml sdk is only for xlsx. if you can get your users to upgrade, great. otherwise if you want to edit the same file they gave you, you are going to have to do excel interop. or write a new file as CSV.